# antd table: why record.key returns undefined when I have set the rowkey

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

[image]

[image]

The table has `rowkey` which is equal to the column `"mac"`, but I can not get the key by `record.key`, it returns undefined, but `record.mac` works?

Comment: there are a few properties on a react component that are internal to the component. `children` is one, and another is `key`. React defines keys for every element / component and uses it for rendering performance purposes

Comment: Please post code not an image

Answer (score 5):

The `rowKey` property at `Table` component accepts a `function` or a `string` if it's a single row table:

> rowKey -  Row's unique key, could be a string or function that returns a
>   string    `string|Function(record):string`

You **should always provide a function**, for example, if `dataSource` has `key` property: `record => record.key`

```js
<Table columns={columns} dataSource={dataSource} rowKey={record => record.key} />;
```

Answer (score 0):

> The reason is that the concept of a key is something that is
>   controlled by React internals before your component gets created.

You should define props.

Answer (score 0):

the `<Table />` component will take in a columnMap that maps to your dataSource.

You will need to set a rowKey if the objects in your dataSource don't specify a key parameter:

```js
const dataSource = [{
 id: 123,
 name: 'Karl',
 nested: { id: 456 },
 mac: "some-unique-identifier"
}, ...]
```

alternatively, you can append one to your data and you don't need a rowKey:

```js
const dataSource = [{
 id: 123,
 name: 'Karl',
 nested: { id: 456 },
 key: 123,
 mac: "some-unique-identifier"
}, ...]
```

this requires an extra step in processing.

usage with no 'key' parameter:

```
render() {
  return <Table
          dataSource={dataSource}
          columns={unspecifiedColumnNames}
          rowKey={(row) => row.id || row.nested.id || row.mac} // either 123 || 456 || "some-unique-identifier"
         />
}
```

It seems at least in antd 4.16.13 the `rowKey` parameter is to be deprecated. I just append a key parameter to my dataSource manually instead of doing it in the `rowKey` attribute's function.